# How to combine Ruby regexp conditions

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, regex

I need to check if a string is valid image url.
I want to check beginning of string and end of string as follows:

- Must start with http(s):
- Must end by .jpg|.png|.gif|.jpeg

So far I have:

```
(https?:)
```

I can't seem to indicate beginning of string `\A`, combine patterns, and test end of string.

Test strings:

```
"http://image.com/a.jpg"
"https://image.com/a.jpg"
"ssh://image.com/a.jpg"
"http://image.com/a.jpeg"
"https://image.com/a.png"
"ssh://image.com/a.jpeg"
```

Please see http://rubular.com/r/PqERRim5RQ

Using Ruby 2.5

Comment: So people down in the answers section are having an argument about whether your "test strings" are (1) **many strings, one per line**, with no whitespace or (2) a **single string** where a regex has to match each individual line. Can you edit the question to clarify that?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You may use

```
reg = %r{\Ahttps?://.*\.(?:png|gif|jpe?g)\z}
```

The point is:

1. When *testing* at online regex testers, you are testing a *single multiline* string, but in real life, you will validate lines as *separate* strings. So, in those testers, use `^` and `$` and in real code, use `\A` and `\z`.
2. To match a string rather than a line you need `\A` and `\z` anchors
3. Use `%r{pat}` syntax if you have many `/` in your pattern, it is cleaner.

[Online Ruby test](https://ideone.com/vJZE5T):

```
urls = ['http://image.com/a.jpg',
        'https://image.com/a.jpg',
        'ssh://image.com/a.jpg',
        'http://image.com/a.jpeg',
        'https://image.com/a.png',
        'ssh://image.com/a.jpeg']
reg = %r{\Ahttps?://.*\.(?:png|gif|jpe?g)\z}
urls.each { |url|
    puts "#{url}: #{(reg =~ url) == 0}"
}
```

Output:

```
http://image.com/a.jpg: true
https://image.com/a.jpg: true
ssh://image.com/a.jpg: false
http://image.com/a.jpeg: true
https://image.com/a.png: true
ssh://image.com/a.jpeg: false
```

Comment: Thanks for the explanations. Much appreciated

Answer (score 5):

Using your very own demo, you could use

```
^https?:\/\/.*(?:\.jpg|\.png|\.gif|\.jpeg)$
```

See [**the modified demo**](http://rubular.com/r/nCFwsT7eEE).

---

One could even simplify it to:

```
^https?:\/\/.*\.(?:jpe?g|png|gif)$
```

See [**a demo for the latter as well**](http://rubular.com/r/Xh82wfAcRT).

---

This basically uses anchors (`^` and `$`) on both sides, indicating the start/end of the string. Additionally, please remember that you need to escape the dot (`\.`) if you want to have `.`.

---

There's quite some ambiguity going on in the comments section, so let me clarify this:

```
^  - is meant for the start of a string 
     (or a line in multiline mode, but in Ruby strings are always in multiline mode)
$  - is meant for the end of a string / line
\A - is the very start of a string (irrespective of multilines) 
\z - is the very end of a string (irrespective of multilines)
```

Comment: Hi Can you explain me why `?:` was used?

Comment: @Rajagopalan: See the expression when no groups are used: https://regex101.com/r/XNdihh/1 - it simply matches elsewhere.

Comment: I am still not clear as to why. Okay, what about this `^https?:\/\/.*\.(jpe?g|png|gif$)` ?

Comment: This obviously matches `"foo\nhttp.....jpg\nbar"` which neither starts with `"http"` nor ends with `"jpg"`. _Always_ use `\A` and `\z` anchors instead of `^` and `$` unless you perfectly understand the circumstances.

Comment: @mudasobwa Are you sure there is one instance of a URL at a moment to use `\A`?

Comment: I think you don't need second grouping: `^https?:\/\/.*\.(?:jpe?g|png|gif)$`

Comment: @revo I am good at reading first sentences of the OP. It states: “I need to check if _a string_ **is** valid image url.”

Comment: @mudasobwa And I hope you are good at reading OP's provided demo in which there are URLs each in a single line?

Comment: @revo: Thanks, that's exactly the point of using `^` and `$` over `\A` and `\Z`.

Comment: @Rajagopalan coming back to your query (?:exp) is used by jan becasue it provides grouping without capturing or backreference. Your suggestion will work too but it will create a capture group which is not necessarily needed. `"http://image.com/a.jpeg".match(/^https?:\/\/.*(\.jpg|\.png|\.gif|\.jpeg)$/)[1] == '.jpeg'`

Comment: Thank you all for your explanations.

Answer (score 1):

The answers here are quite good, but if you wanted to avoid using a complicated regex and communicate your intent more clearly to a reader, you could let `URI` and `File` do the heavy lifting for you.

(And since you're using 2.5, let's use `#match?` instead of other regex-matching methods.)

```
def valid_url?(url)
  # Let URI parse the URL.
  uri = URI.parse(url)
  # Is the scheme http or https, and does the extension match expected formats?
  uri.scheme.match?(/https?/i) && File.extname(uri.path).match?(/(png|jpe?g|gif)/i)
rescue URI::InvalidURIError
  # If it's an invalid URL, URI will throw this error.
  # We'll return `false`, because a URL that can't be parsed by URI isn't valid.
  false
end

urls.map { |url| [url, valid_url?(url)] }

#=> Results in:
'http://image.com/a.jpg', true
'https://image.com/a.jpg', true
'ssh://image.com/a.jpg', false
'http://image.com/a.jpeg', true
'https://image.com/a.png', true
'ssh://image.com/a.jpeg', false
'https://image.com/a.tif', false
'http://t.co.uk/proposal.docx', false
'not a url', false
```